# have IIS logs get client name

Tags: iis, logging, request-headers, response-headers

I'm attempting to use the custom fields features created in IIS 8.5 to log the Client Name as well as (or instead of) the Client IP. When parsing through the logs, it's important that if a username is not supplied by the page that I have another way to identify the user.  Trying to lookup all these IPs is time consuming, and makes runtime for any programs doing so incredibly slow.  If anyone know how to configure this field, or can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could run this PowerShell command:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "system.webServer/security/ipSecurity" -name "enableReverseDns" -value "True"
```

Replace `Default Web Site` with your site's name, you also need `IIS Management Scripts and Tools` installed.

**but you really, really shouldn't.**

As you write yourself:

> Trying to lookup all these IPs is time consuming,

IIS does not do this after a request has been answered, it does this before it processes it and therefore makes your whole web server much slower than before.

When changing this in the GUI, you get:

[image: IIS dialog box]

Comment: Do you know of any way to force the client to send it's name?  It's essential to this project that I can figure out who is accessing these pages within the group.